# Spring Stomp over Websocket: Stream large files

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

My SockJs client in webpage, sends message with a frame size of 16K. The message size limit is what determines the max size of the file that I can transfer.

Below is what I found in the doc.

```
/**
 * Configure the maximum size for an incoming sub-protocol message.
 * For example a STOMP message may be received as multiple WebSocket messages
 * or multiple HTTP POST requests when SockJS fallback options are in use.
 *
 * <p>In theory a WebSocket message can be almost unlimited in size.
 * In practice WebSocket servers impose limits on incoming message size.
 * STOMP clients for example tend to split large messages around 16K
 * boundaries. Therefore a server must be able to buffer partial content
 * and decode when enough data is received. Use this property to configure
 * the max size of the buffer to use.
 *
 * <p>The default value is 64K (i.e. 64 * 1024).
 *
 * <p><strong>NOTE</strong> that the current version 1.2 of the STOMP spec
 * does not specifically discuss how to send STOMP messages over WebSocket.
 * Version 2 of the spec will but in the mean time existing client libraries
 * have already established a practice that servers must handle.
 */
public WebSocketTransportRegistration setMessageSizeLimit(int messageSizeLimit) {
    this.messageSizeLimit = messageSizeLimit;
    return this;
}
```

**MY QUESTION:**
Can I setup a partial messaging so that a file is transferred part by part and is not getting transferred as a single message as it is been done now?

Update:
Still looking for a solution with partial messaging
Meanwhile using HTTP now for large messages (which is file uploads/downloads in my application).

Comment: I have landed here as I am trying this myself. I have the solution that you are looking for but on the server side I don;t want to receive part by part but rather a stream (which is still part-by-part but using internal buffers) Wondering if you found a better solution or need at-least that solution.

Comment: I switched to HTTP for only the file transferring now, so if you have a *stream* solution via websockets, that would be great..

Comment: I have posted the answer and while my immediate motivation is reducing the memory spikes for uploading large file on my single page app which on measurements meets my requirements the experimental project I linked is primitive at best and it is just a PoC.

Answer (score 6):

> Can I setup a partial messaging so that a file is transferred part by part and is not getting transferred as a single message as it is been done now?

Yes. Here is the relevant Config from my Spring boot experimental project - basically `UploadWSHandler` is registered and `WebSocketTransportRegistration.setMessageSizeLimit` is set.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new UploadWSHandler(), "/binary");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
        registration.setMessageSizeLimit(50 * 1024 * 1024);
    }
}
```

The UploadWShandler is as follows. Sorry too much code here - Key points

- `supportsPartialMessage` which returns true.
- `handleBinaryMessage` will be called multiple times with partial message so we need to assemble the bytes. So `afterConnectionEstablished` establishes an identity using the websocket URL query. But you don't have to use this mechanism. The reason why I choose this mechanism is to keep the client side simple so that I call `webSocket.send(files[0])` only once i.e. I am not slicing the file blob object on the javascript side. (side point: I want to use plain websocket on client side - no stomp/socks)
- The iternal client side chunking mechanism provides `message.isLast()` last message
- For demo purposes I am writing this to file system and accumulating those bytes in memory with `FileUploadInFlight` but you don't have to do this and can stream somewhere else as you go.

```
public class UploadWSHandler extends BinaryWebSocketHandler {

    Map<WebSocketSession, FileUploadInFlight> sessionToFileMap = new WeakHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public boolean supportsPartialMessages() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleBinaryMessage(WebSocketSession session, BinaryMessage message) throws Exception {
        ByteBuffer payload = message.getPayload();
        FileUploadInFlight inflightUpload = sessionToFileMap.get(session);
        if (inflightUpload == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("This is not expected");
        }
        inflightUpload.append(payload);

        if (message.isLast()) {
            Path basePath = Paths.get(".", "uploads", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            Files.createDirectories(basePath);
            FileChannel channel = new FileOutputStream(
                    Paths.get(basePath.toString() ,inflightUpload.name).toFile(), false).getChannel();
            channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(inflightUpload.bos.toByteArray()));
            channel.close();
            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("UPLOAD "+inflightUpload.name));
            session.close();
            sessionToFileMap.remove(session);
        }
        String response = "Upload Chunk: size "+ payload.array().length;
        System.out.println(response);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        sessionToFileMap.put(session, new FileUploadInFlight(session));
    }

    static class FileUploadInFlight {
        String name;
        String uniqueUploadId;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        /**
         * Fragile constructor - beware not prod ready
         * @param session
         */
        FileUploadInFlight(WebSocketSession session) {
            String query = session.getUri().getQuery();
            String uploadSessionIdBase64 = query.split("=")[1];
            String uploadSessionId = new String(Base64Utils.decodeUrlSafe(uploadSessionIdBase64.getBytes()));
            System.out.println(uploadSessionId);
            List<String> sessionIdentifiers = Splitter.on("\\").splitToList(uploadSessionId);
            String uniqueUploadId = session.getRemoteAddress().toString()+sessionIdentifiers.get(0);
            String fileName = sessionIdentifiers.get(1);
            this.name = fileName;
            this.uniqueUploadId = uniqueUploadId;
        }
        public void append(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) throws IOException{
            bos.write(byteBuffer.array());
        }
    }
}
```

BTW a working project is also [sprint-boot-with-websocked-chunking-assembly-and-fetch](https://github.com/yogeshgadge/spring-websocket-fileupload/tree/with-websocked-chunking-assembly-and-fetch) in `with-websocked-chunking-assembly-and-fetch` branch

Comment: Actually AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer is deprecated and Spring suggests to use WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer, but do you know how could I add the WebSocketHandlerRegistry?

Comment: I did it by adding "implements WebSocketConfigurer" to the class description and adding the @EnableWebSocket annotation on the class.

Comment: @bhantol By the way, wouldn't it be better to use a thread-safe Map implementation?

Comment: @BullshitPingu Thread safe would be a overkill since `handleBinaryMessage` which is part of `handleMessage` is invoked when messages starts arriving and will not get invoked before connection is ready `afterConnectionEstablished`. I would be surprised if `afterConnectionEstablished` is asynchronous because that would defeat its purpose. Normally in networking the purposes of such events is to let you prepare for the readiness for receiving messages. You could get defensive and make it thread safe. (PS. I did not look into the implementation source code.)