# How to process binary messages as input streams?

Tags: java, websocket, spring-websocket

I want to implement upload of large files via WebSockets and have the server store the files in a database or an object store.

I'm trying out the `spring-websocket` library and, as far as I understood, I need to extend the `BinaryWebSocketHandler` class and implement the file storage there.

```java
public class MyWebSocketHandler extends BinaryWebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    protected void handleBinaryMessage(WebSocketSession session, BinaryMessage message) throws Exception {
          // Store file in DB/OS...
    }

}
```

While this looks wonderful, my problem is that the `BinaryMessage` I get to handle only allows me to work with `ByteBuffer`s. I assume this means that the entire file is loaded in-memory and stored in this `ByteBuffer` object (unless I also override the `supportsPartialMessages` method, of course). Is this correct?

If yes, this would be a huge problem for me, since storing large files in-memory is not something I want to do. I was expecting to be able to get access to an `InputStream` and read the file from there. It also seems like this should be possible, seeing as `spring-websocket` uses the Java WebSocket API under the hood, and they allow `MessageHandler`s to handle `InputStream`s (see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/MessageHandler.Whole.html).

Unfortunately, I cannot find any way of getting access to an `InputStream` in my handler. Does anyone know whether this is actually possible? If not, would this make sense as a feature request or would this be a misuse of WebSockets somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `AbstractWebSocketHandler.supportsPartialMessages`, which states that:

> If this flag is set to true and the underlying WebSocket server supports partial messages, then a large WebSocket message, or one of an unknown size may be split and maybe received over multiple calls to WebSocketHandler.handleMessage(WebSocketSession, WebSocketMessage). The flag WebSocketMessage.isLast() indicates if the message is partial and whether it is the last part.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/WebSocketHandler.html

Comment: I know about partial messages, but if I use those, it becomes much much harder to persist the file in a database or an object store. When I receive chunk #1, I can easily insert it into the DB, but how would I then append chunk #2 when it comes along? I don't know of any database agnostic SQL statement that would allow me to do that.

That's why I want to work with an `InputStream` and not with a byte array.

Comment: Instead of writing to DB, you may want to write to a temporary file, and on `isLast` insert that file into the database. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896551/spring-stomp-over-websocket-stream-large-files
One issue I didn't see addressed there is of abandoned transfers.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this, since my application is running in a container with limited disk space, so using temporary files could lead to a crash if a lot of uploads are triggered at the same time. Using Spring WebMVC and HTTP, I could get access to an `InputStream` and pass it to the database directly. I was hoping that the same would be achievable with web sockets, but apparently this is not the case. I'll try opening a feature request in their GitHub page. Maybe there's a reason for that. Thanks for pointing me to the related question. Apparently, other people are also interested in this.

Comment: Maybe it's worth relying on WebMVC / HTTP for such uploads only, for example a message via the socket could "request" a port and permission to upload a file, which is then handled separately. By linking the two you may be able to directly associate the websocket session with the file and stick to websocket for everything else.

Comment: I actually want to opposite - use web sockets for file upload and HTTP for everything else. Before the request reaches my application, it goes through a router application (namely Cloud Foundry's GoRouter). This router terminates every request that hasn't received a response in 15 minutes, which could easily happen if the uploading file is large and/or the user has a slow internet connection. The router doesn't, however, terminate web socket communication (at least as far as I know).